# presenting a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to go to a view controller when the button "Cancel" is pressed. I tried using this method but when I click 'Cancel", it just displays a black screen. I am a beginner at IOS.

```
 -(void) cancelButtonPressed {

    homeView = (HomeViewController *)[[UIViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:homeView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

EDITED FOR COMMENTS:

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed)];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
```

Comment: where did u put your button ? How you initialized ur button ?

Comment: it is a left bar button item.

Comment: i suggest you to read some tutorials online!!!! IS it on the navigation bar ?

Comment: where did you declared homeView ? and what is homeVIew in cancel method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
     HomeViewController *homeView = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
     [self presentViewController:homeView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also note that black is the default colour of the window. If you don't have any view controller named HomeViewController, and you present it, by default it will be visible as black colour to the user.

To Avoid this, you need to set the View for the newly presented view controller, which you can access by `homeView.view`

If you are using storyboard, then use storyboard ID:

```
     HomeViewController *homeView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
      [self presentViewController:homeView animated:YES completion:nil];
```